# Why does my dropdown need to be clicked twice to open?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4.3.1 to make a website and I'm having some trouble with opening the dropdown menus. I'm using the bootstrap class "dropdown" in my div.

```html
<div class="dropdown" style="float: right;">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="float: right">
        "HAMLB"<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">HAMLB</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">HAMLU</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">HAMMB</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">HAMRG</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I first open the page or I refresh the page, I have to click on the dropdown menu button twice in order to open it. After selecting something or closing the menu, I need only click the button once to open the dropdown menu again, as is expected.

Comment: There might be a clash with some custom styles, the snippet you provided works: https://jsfiddle.net/v8qdjLwx/1/

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and It works correctly. Your problem is most likely in your stylesheet. Can you show your CSS file ?